# Is it safe to expose auto increment id in URL

Tags: mysql

Am using GET method to retrieve data from database. Am using Mysql DB and PHP to retrieve data. And my URL look like this

```
    "http://localhost/test/index.php?prop_id=1&location_id=1"

     "prop_id" is my auto increment field in my database "property" table
```

Could any one of you tell me if this is safe or not.. Also tell me the best practice..

thanks

Comment: You should use POST instead if security is a concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best Practice" varies from programmer to programmer and company to company.  A good line of inquiry to use when thinking about security is to look at everything that can be done as something that a hacker, idiot user, or cat walking across the keyboard could do.  In your case, you are giving a good means for someone to access other data records.

Is this safe?  That depends on your code and how your site is implemented.  Is it okay for someone to be able to see every record?  Can they alter, delete, or otherwise damage someone else's data if they do so?

Encrypting or encoding the id is an idea, but then you are just reducing the ease of accessing it.  Someone with enough time on their hands could probably still access the data, which goes back to the point in the previous paragraph.

Consider using things like Post, session variables, or other things instead of querystring/Get variables.

Comment: this is a good explanation and i appreciate your time.. thanks a lot and i will consider doing so..

Answer (score 1):

No, nobody can tell you if that is safe or not because you've given us absolutely no context to work with.

Does it matter if people can add one to the ID and see the next record?

If no, it's safe.

If yes, it's not safe.

Comment: What if i encrypt my IDs.. Still is it possible for someone to get the actual ID

Comment: You still haven't answered whether it's even important that your IDs not be guessable. If that *is* important, no, encryption has nothing to do with the solution. Just use non-guessable IDs.